# Atmel USART and TCC interaction issues

Tags: c, embedded, atmel, atmelstudio

am new to the embedded MCU ATSAML22, and am learning from the examples provided by the Atmel Studio 7.0.

I would like to have an USART communication reading byte by byte using a callback function (**usart_read_callback()**) that can detect with a TCC timer (*pending to integrate*), when the sending of the data has finished (example after 1 sec of no data sent, consider it as transmission finished).

The final idea is that carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) are part of the transmitted data and they don´t determine the end of the transmitted data, but the timer will.

Thanks in advance

*Actual status of the code*

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void usart_read_callback(struct usart_module *const usart_module);
void usart_write_callback(struct usart_module *const usart_module);

void configure_usart(void);
void configure_usart_callbacks(void);

//! [module_inst]
struct usart_module usart_instance;
//! [module_inst]

//! [rx_buffer_var]
#define MAX_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH   1

volatile uint8_t rx_buffer[MAX_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
//! [rx_buffer_var]

//! [callback_funcs]
void usart_read_callback(struct usart_module *const usart_module)
{
    usart_write_buffer_job(&usart_instance,
            (uint8_t *)rx_buffer, MAX_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH);
}

void usart_write_callback(struct usart_module *const usart_module)
{
    port_pin_toggle_output_level(LED_0_PIN);
}
//! [callback_funcs]

//! [setup]
void configure_usart(void)
{
//! [setup_config]
    struct usart_config config_usart;
//! [setup_config]
//! [setup_config_defaults]
    usart_get_config_defaults(&config_usart);
//! [setup_config_defaults]

#if(SAMR30E)
{
    config_usart.baudrate    = 9600;
    config_usart.mux_setting = CDC_SERCOM_MUX_SETTING;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad0 = CDC_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD0;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad1 = CDC_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD1;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad2 = CDC_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD2;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad3 = CDC_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD3;
    //! [setup_change_config]

    //! [setup_set_config]
    while (usart_init(&usart_instance,
    CDC_MODULE, &config_usart) != STATUS_OK) {
    }
    //! [setup_set_config]
}
#else
{
    config_usart.baudrate    = 9600;
    config_usart.mux_setting = EXT1_UART_SERCOM_MUX_SETTING;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad0 = EXT1_UART_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD0;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad1 = EXT1_UART_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD1;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad2 = EXT1_UART_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD2;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad3 = EXT1_UART_SERCOM_PINMUX_PAD3;
    //! [setup_change_config]

    //! [setup_set_config]
    while (usart_init(&usart_instance,
    EXT1_UART_MODULE, &config_usart) != STATUS_OK) {
    }
    //! [setup_set_config]
}
#endif

//! [setup_enable]
    usart_enable(&usart_instance);
//! [setup_enable]
}

void configure_usart_callbacks(void)
{
//! [setup_register_callbacks]
    usart_register_callback(&usart_instance,
            usart_write_callback, USART_CALLBACK_BUFFER_TRANSMITTED);
    usart_register_callback(&usart_instance,
            usart_read_callback, USART_CALLBACK_BUFFER_RECEIVED);
//! [setup_register_callbacks]

//! [setup_enable_callbacks]
    usart_enable_callback(&usart_instance, USART_CALLBACK_BUFFER_TRANSMITTED);
    usart_enable_callback(&usart_instance, USART_CALLBACK_BUFFER_RECEIVED);
//! [setup_enable_callbacks]
}
//! [setup]


int main(void)
{
    system_init();

//! [setup_init]
    configure_usart();
    configure_usart_callbacks();
//! [setup_init]

//! [main]
//! [enable_global_interrupts]
    system_interrupt_enable_global();
//! [enable_global_interrupts]

//! [main_send_string]
    uint8_t string[] = "\r\n==================== My Test ====================\r\n";
    usart_write_buffer_wait(&usart_instance, string, sizeof(string)-1 );
//! [main_send_string]

//! [main_loop]
    while (true) {
//! [main_loop]
//! [main_read]
        usart_read_buffer_job(&usart_instance,
                (uint8_t *)rx_buffer, MAX_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH);
//! [main_read]
    }
//! [main]
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn´t clear. Want to know how to integrate a TCC timer for the USART callback read function.

Comment: Ok. Any particular reason why you aren't using DMA?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Basically cause the length of the transmitted data is variable, it will include CR and LF in it for better human readability, and because of the idea of inactivity when no typing any commands fits the purpose of the project.